# Which is the subject of this sentence?

Tags: grammar, subjects

I want to know, how to identify subject and predicate of such long sentence?

Talking about our old family holidays has made me feel all nostalgic.

Answer (score 2):

The subject is "talking about our old family holidays."

Normally in declarative sentences in English, the subject precedes the verb. Here the verb is "has made."

A subject need not be a noun or pronoun. A participle can be used as a noun and is then called a gerund.

> Swimming is good exercise.

The subject is the gerund "swimming," and the meaning is the activity denoted by the root verb of the participle.

But a participle can take an object or modifiers. In which case the entire phrase of participle plus object and modifiers becomes the subject. So your example shows a phrase headed by a gerund as subject.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Talking about our old family holidays*** has made me feel all nostalgic.

The subject is the gerund-participial clause in bold, and the predicate is the verb phrase that follows it, i.e. *has made ne feel all nostalgic*.

We know it's the subject because:

(1) It occupies the basic subject position before the verb.

(2) In subject-auxiliary inversions it occurs after the auxiliary, as in *Has talking about our old family holidays made me feel all nostalgic*?